# Using CSS for results lists with different vertical heights

Tags: css

I'm hoping to make a results list that looks like this:[image: results with different heights]

I used to do that with tables way back when, but always struggle to figure out how to do this with css. What if the description is really long, how do I keep it from wrapping under the image and name/title? This seems harder in CSS than tables, but maybe I'm just missing something. I know tables aren't responsive, which is why I'd like to do it with divs. I just can't stop the text from wrapping.

My HTML is this:

```
            <div class="speaker">

            <div class="speaker-photo">

            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
            <div class="speaker-name"><?php echo $first_name .' '.$last_name; ?></div>
            <div class="speaker-title"><?php echo $title; ?></div>  

            </div>

            <div class="bio"><?php echo $bio ?></div> 

            </div>

            <br style="clear:both;"/>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.speaker {
    margin-bottom: 33px;
}

.speaker-photo  {
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
}

.speaker-photo img {
    max-width: 170px;
    height:auto;
}

.speaker-bio {
    max-width:600px;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: no HTML nor CSS ... no guess nor chocolate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanest approach is to embed the side content and the main content in another element, float the 'sidebar' with a fixed width, and give the main element enough padding to correct it. [See working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/C4znZ/). Keep in mind that this might make for messy `clear`ing if the post on the right is shorter than the sidebar.

Alternatively you could also use [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if backwards compatibility is [not an issue](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), it doesn't have the `clear` issues that always arise from floats.

If you are certain the content is always longer than the sidebar, for example through a `min-height`, you could of course always use `position:absolute` to position the sidebar, and give the right element a margin for the 'gutter'.

Comment: Thanks so much, Niels--I think I'll try the first approach. I really appreciate your help!